# Add post-clean command to python setup.py

Tags: python, hook, setuptools

From resources online, I've learned that the following will add a "post-install" hook if included in `setup.py`:

```
from  setuptools  import  setup
from  setuptools.command.install  import  install  as  _install
class  install(_install):
     def  run(self):
         _install.run(self)
         # Do something magical
setup(cmdclass={'install': install})
```

What I'd like to do, though, is create equivalent behavior after a `setup.py clean` is executed. Specifically, I'd like `setup.py clean` to remove the `.egg-INFO` directory created during the execution of `setup.py egg_info`.

Comment: Please add the reference where you learned this.

Comment: I haven't found a suitable answer for this yet.

Comment: This is unrelated to my request.

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted a reference to where I learned an answer, but I don't have one.

Comment: I asked where _you_ learned this. If you don't want to answer to a comment or read it thoughtfully - it's not obligatory -, please don't comment at all, it just creates work for people who need to clean up this comment section.

Comment: Well, you're creating more work for myself when you don't do your due diligence to research the topic to begin with.