# Include git repo (compile and install with pip) to setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

How to include a git repo in the setup.py setup function that compiles from source, only if the package is not already installed?

I have shell commands from this [instalation manual](https://fenics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#from-source)). I could run these with the `OS module`, though how do I make the pip3 install command robust? What if a user renamed pip3 --> pip? Then my implementation would no longer work.

```
FENICS_VERSION=$(python3 -c"import ffc; print(ffc.__version__)")
git clone --branch=$FENICS_VERSION https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/dolfin
git clone --branch=$FENICS_VERSION https://bitbucket.org/fenics-project/mshr
mkdir dolfin/build && cd dolfin/build && cmake .. && make install && cd ../..
mkdir mshr/build   && cd mshr/build   && cmake .. && make install && cd ../..
cd dolfin/python && pip3 install . && cd ../..
cd mshr/python   && pip3 install . && cd ../..
```

**Background**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950551/how-to-execute-a-safe-bash-shell-command-within-setup-py) and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018117/add-post-clean-command-to-python-setup-py) Question/Answer pose a way to introduce a custom install commands to the setup function in setup.py through a class with a run method.  I assume that in the code below the custom install script is run AFTER it checks the dependencies in `install_requires`.

```
from  setuptools  import  setup
from  setuptools.command.install  import  install  as  _install
import subprocess
class  install(_install):
     def  run(self):
         install.run(self)
         ## do the magic for the installation of mshr and dolfin

setup(name='myProject',
      .......     
     install_requires=['fenics-ffc >= 2018.1.0'],
     setup(cmdclass={'install': install}))
```

Comment: I think it would be cleaner to document your shell setup as a prerequisite for running `pip install myProject`, rather than embedding it. Alternatively, you could publish wheels that include the pre-built dependencies.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Can you give us more details and tell us why you need to do this?